# Minimum code for listening to changes in firestore collection w/ BLOC (flutter)

Tags: flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore, mobx, bloc

I am new to the BlOC style of programming (I usually use mobx, but I want to listen to a collection in firestore and it seems like BLOC is the best way to do this). After reading half a dozen tutorials, I am thoroughly confused. There seem to be API calls, repositories, providers, models, and (most confusing of all) blocs involved in even a simple todo app. I am making a chat app. All I want is a way to listen to the chat collection in firestore, and add new messages to the bottom of the listview containing messages when one is added. Could someone please help me with the bloc structure/code for this? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look into this [link](https://www.davidanaya.io/flutter/architect-flutter.html). It's a complete tutorial to create an app using BlOC pattern.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!